# Seperate 2 logical units on one line in header with css

Tags: html, css

What I want to do is have two logical navigation units in my header. the one with **[1,2,3,4,5]** should be on the left side and the one with **[6,7,8]** on the right.

Right now I have the following HTML code

```
<div id="firstNav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="secondNav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the following CSS

```
#firstNav ul li{
    display: inline-block;

}

#firstNav {
    float:left;
}

#secondNav ul li{
    display: inline-block;

}

#secondNav {
    float:right;
}
```

My Problem is, that if I dont use the inline-block everything is vertical not horizontal and then I force it to be horizontal afterwards in the individual child `<li>` item.

Is this an acceptable way of achieving what I want or can somebody give me a better/more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#firstNav, #firstNav ul li, #secondNav ul li {
    float:left;
}
#secondNav {
    float:right;
}
```

Looks like that's what you need.